# When is the best time to validate an EditText OR an Input Field?

Tags: android, html, validation

I have a form with a few fields in them. I wish to validate all of them before I could submit the details entered. For example, First Name should have atleast 1 character. Email should match the Email-format. Password should be atleast 6 characters and so on...

Based on the validation, I have to put a green-right-tick or a red-cross symbol at the end of the field.

I'm working on an android app, but I think a similar problem could occur in a web app too.

Now, my question is when should I validate the fields? By validating, I mean either I put the right-tick or, the wrong-cross with Error Message. Here are the options that I'm considering right now:

1. I validate them with every keystroke.
2. I validate a particular field when focus from that field goes away. That's when the user is done typing into that field.
3. I start validating when a user pauses typing for sometime, say 0.5 seconds.

I know the question might be opinion-based, but from the perspective of an End user, what would be the best experience?

Comment: I would say the second one. This way the user kind of "control" the validation, it's a mind thing :) also it's the cleaniest way I think

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then I realized how would I validate the last field? Because I will be pressing the submit button when the cursor is still in the `EditText` box. Thus, no validation could be done.

Comment: There is and Event for the keyboard Next button you just have to catch it with the listener

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the use cases that you need to cover.

- There can be an use case where whenever user presses submit button or trying to move to next screen/page the validation should happen
- There are general use cases where whenever user jumps to next field validation should happen for the previous field

All these depends on the business analysis stage and you may not get a specific solution for this

Answer (score -1):

As Harry says there is no consolidated-straightforward answer to this but if I should choose one of your proposed choices I would say when the focus of a field goes away. Has the less procesing load and do not disturb the user as much as the other 2 options.
I do not like validating this kind of fields when the whole form is submitted.